# Broken version history after migrating to Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-foundation, migration

I had a WSS3.0 instaliation with forms based authentication, and I wish to migrate to SP2013.
I have SP2010 and SP2013 servers, I've successfully detached content database from WSS 3.0, attached to SP2010, detached and atached to SP2013, performed following:

```
Convert-SPWebApplication -Identity http://Your-Server-Name -To Claims -RetainPermissions
```

It renamed all the users in UserInfo table to "i:0#.f|provider|*", but kept the old names (provider:*) in all metadata:
 - documents author, modifiedby (this is not a big issue, I wrote a script to fix it)
 - documents version history, same situation, problem is that versions are read only from API/powershell side.

Has anyone else faced this situation (I guess there should be many people with same problem, just wondering why I can find any solutions on internet).

Comment: did you run the migrate user command?

Comment: I've tried all the Migrate* combinations, but from what I saw in decompiled source code, they all boil down to the same method.

Comment: Is this a Person or Group list you're referring to?

Comment: @GeorgeGrainger - not sure if understood question correctly, I working with SPDocumentList type lists.

Comment: *Person or Group field within the list. Apologies, my mistake

Comment: To fields in properties - vti_author and vti_modifiedby

Comment: Waiting to hear something from you regarding my answer...@Giedrius

Answer (score 2):

You can try following script to rename provider. I have used it while migrating one domain to separate domain.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

$web = Get-SPWeb -identity "http://Web Application URL"

$user = $null 
$newuserID = $null 
$OlduserID = $null 

$OlduserID = 'i:0#.f|provider_old\{LoginName}'
$newuserID = 'i:0#.f|provider_new\{LoginName}' 
$user = Get-SPUser -Web $web -Identity $OlduserID #-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

If($user) { 
    $newuserID = $web.EnsureUser($newuserID) 
    Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias $NewuserID -Confirm:$false -IgnoreSID 
    Write-Host " Migrated"
} Else{
Write-Host "Unable to Migrate"
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it didn't helped - it renamed users, but not document/versions authors/modifiers.

Comment: That is unfortunate! In my environment it worked